# Display value of custom field not working

Tags: custom-field, plugin-types

I am simply trying to print the value of a custom field. I have read all the documentation, tried out other people's suggestions, and nothing works. I can get it to print the ID #, but not the actual value I have in the field. I am using the Types plugin to create the field.

this prints the ID:

```
<?php echo get_the_ID($value, 'authorinfo', true); ?>
```

as well as:

```
<?php echo get_the_ID($key, 'authorinfo', true); ?>
```

this does nothing:

```
<?php get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'authorinfo', true ); ?>
```

this does nothing:

```
<?php echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'authorinfo', true); ?>
```

(I have a separate question on this site where the problem came up and a solution was offered but unfortunately it didn't work for me) - [Display custom post type and custom fields within a Bootstrap Carousel](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/72064/display-custom-post-type-and-custom-fields-within-a-bootstrap-carousel)

Here is all the code I'm working within in case that helps. I hope I'm doing something stupid here.

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel">
        <div class="carousel-inner">

          <?php $the_query = new WP_Query(array(
            'post_type' => 'testimonial', 
            'posts_per_page' => 1 
            ));
            while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
            <div class="item active" data-title="">
                <div class="slide-copy">
                    <?php the_content();?>
                    <span class="byline"><?php echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'authorinfo', true); ?></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
            <?php $the_query = new WP_Query(array(
            'post_type' => 'testimonial', 
            'posts_per_page' => 5, 
            'offset' => 1 
            ));
            while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
            <div class="item" data-title="">
                <div class="slide-copy">
                    <?php the_content();?>
                    <span class="byline"><?php echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'authorinfo', true); ?></span>
                </div>
            </div>

            <?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div><!-- end myCarousel -->

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

**EDIT/ADDITION**

Since working with the Types plugin more, I am pretty sure this problem could be solved by using "types_render_field" instead of "get_post_meta". I don't have a place where I can test this, but I think this should help someone with a similar problem.

Comment: `<?php echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'authorinfo', true); ?>` is correct. If it's not working, it might have something to do with how your plugin saves the data. Can't say further as i'm unfamiliar with that plugin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Types plugin is making this about 10x harder than it needs to be, you'll have to look through their documentation on the issue, but from what I can tell they don't store items in the `postmeta` table in a straightforward way. I created a simple field with the plugin in a sandbox env and the `meta_key` for a field I named `data` was `wpcf-data`. You may want to take your post ID and do this in your DB:

```
SELECT * FROM wp_postmeta WHERE post_id = NNNN;
```

where `NNNN` is your post ID. You may see a `wpcf-authorinfo` key, that is likely then the key you should be passing to `get_post_meta`:

```
echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'wpcf-authorinfo', TRUE);
```

Comment: thanks, you are awesome. unfortunately with my deadline today i am going to pass on trying that out, but i'm going to mark it as an answer because it sounds like it might help someone else. i decided to switch to the Advanced Custom Fields plugin and now i'm back in business. thanks!

Comment: Also possibly helpful for tracking down the actual `meta_key` you could use `SELECT * FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key LIKE '%authorinfo%';`

Comment: Way old post obviously, but I can confirm that Types adds wpcf- as a prefix to any custom meta fields you make with it.

Comment: This answer proved to be helpful, the Types plugin doesn't have a way to retrieve the items other than their way which is inflexible.

Answer (score 1):

I would try:

```
echo get_post_meta( $the_query->post->ID, 'authorinfo', true);
```

although I do agree with Mridul Aggarwal that

```
<?php echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'authorinfo', true); ?>
```

should also work.

Comment: Thank you! I'm going to mark this as the answer, even though it didn't fix it for me. I'm ruling my problem as a fluke. Gonna experiment with some other options for custom fields. (btw, diggin' your bootstrap theme!)

Answer (score 1):

Easier than that!
Just do:

```
echo types_render_field("description");
```

Where the "description" is the name of the custom field.
This will print the value of "description" of your post / post type.

Here is this documentation of Wordpress Types plugin:
http://wp-types.com/documentation/user-guides/displaying-wordpress-custom-fields/#1

This only works for "types plugin". If you are using "Advanced custom fields plugin" you should use:

```
echo get_field('description');
```